# Get base64 string from existing png not working

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I need the base64-string (not URL) from an existing PNG (photo from a text document).

I use the following function to receive base64-String for my photo. The string, which I get back, is valid but if I test it in a online decoder, I get this image:

[image]

imageResult is an image-Element in my DOM. Any hints what is going wrong?

**JS**

```
var img = this.imageResult.nativeElement;
var ocrImage = this.getBase64Image(img);

getBase64Image(img) {
 var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
 canvas.width = img.width;
 canvas.height = img.height;
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
 var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
 return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

Comment: 0) What does the image you're starting with look like? (1) What is the purpose of stripping-out info returned by toDataURL?

Comment: 0) the image is a simple png of an text document. 1) I want to send the base64 informations to an api endpoint

Comment: Great, thanks for the extra info. Any chance of supplying the original source image? It will certainly aid the effort of debugging. I'm sure you can appreciate the difficulty with which one can trace the path from "a simple png of a text document" to the actual bits in the result. :)